# Hive Join multiple tables and where statements

Tags: mysql, database, hadoop, hive

so I've done anything with databases, so this may be very easy; but, I would find it quite helpful (both practically and for my own knowledge) if someone could help me do this.

Set up: There are 3 tables as follows;

Table 1: userToPizza

col1 = user (a bigint) col2 = pizza (a bigint)

Table 2: pizzaConversion

col1 = pizza (a bigint) col2 = oven_loc (a string in type, but an int in life)

Table 3: ovenToFire

col1 = oven_loc (a bigint) col2 = fire_loc (a bigint)

Now What I'm trying to do is as follows:

1. SELECT pizza FROM userToPIzza WHERE user = 1
2. After I have all these pizzas, I want to do SELECT oven_loc FROM pizzaConversion WHERE pizza = {all those pizzas I just got}
3. Basically do the same step as above on the last table, i.e: SELECT fire_loc FORM ovenToFire WHERE oven_loc = cast({all those ovens I just got} as bigint)

Thank you. Sorry if this is really easy :( but I would really appreciate some help. Also, ps I'm pretty sure to actually query like this I need to use JOINs, but I'm not exactly sure how to do that -- so hopefully the above is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the below queries shall help you.

Query-1 Solution:

SELECT userToPIzza.pizza FROM userToPIzza WHERE userToPIzza.user = 1

Query-2 Solution:

SELECT pizzaConversion.oven_loc FROM userToPIzza JOIN pizzaConversion ON (userToPIzza.pizza = pizzaConversion.pizza) WHERE userToPIzza.user = 1

Query-3 Solution:

SELECT ovenToFire.fire_loc FROM userToPIzza JOIN pizzaConversion ON (userToPIzza.pizza = pizzaConversion.pizza) JOIN ovenToFire ON (ovenToFire.oven_loc = pizzaConversion.oven_loc) WHERE userToPIzza.user = 1